# Initialise a 2D array all to the same value?

Tags: c, arrays

I was wondering if it's possible in C to initialise every element of a 2D array to the same value. I declare my 2D array like this:

```
char arry[x][y];
```

and I want every element arry[0...x][0...y] to contain the asterisks character. Is there any simple way to do this without loops? I'm thinking something like:

```
char arry[x][y] = '*'
```

But I know that doesn't work.

Comment: Tip: Use [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/). It does not initialize the array but sets all members to desired value in one single statement, I believe that is what you desire.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid looping. Programming is pretty hard without loops.

Comment: @AlokSave memset uses loops.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use [scalar initializer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html):

```
// Define row and column
int row = 4, col = 5;
// Initialize 2D character array
char array2D[row][col] = {[0 ... (row-1)][0 ... (col-1)] = '*'};

// Print array to screen
printf("\nArray:\n");

for(int x = 0; x < row; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < col; y++)
        printf("%c\t", array2D[x][y]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

You can see that output:

```
Array:
*   *   *   *   *   
*   *   *   *   *   
*   *   *   *   *   
*   *   *   *   *
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible as long as "the same value" is zero

```
char arry[x][y] = { 0 };
```

The above will initialize *all* elements of the array with zeros.

For any other value, it is not possible through initialization syntax (unless you want to spell that "same value" for each array element explicitly). You will either write your own initialization cycle or use a pre-written function.

Comment: OP specifically says a particular value, namely `*`.

Comment: @Alok Save: Both the `'*'` and `char` as array element type is just *an example*. The OP says "for example". The question proper does not talk about `*` and/or `char`. So, `memset` is not really the right answer.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. I do want to initialise the entire thing to `*`

Comment: @rheotron: Great. The answer still stands though: there's no way. `memset` will sort of "work" (a "pre-written function"), but it will be a hack anyway. Steamrolling over a 2D array with `memset` is not a very elegant solution, to put it mildly. And of course `memset` is a rather thinly veiled loop and you wanted to do it without loops.

Comment: Yeah - that's what I was thinking. It's a fairly simple program and I want to keep it as elegant as possible. With the code you've provided above, I get the error `variable-sized objects may not be initialized`.

Comment: @rheotron: That's a different story. Evidently your `x` or your `y` (or both) are not constants. This turns your array into a variable sized array (VLA). VLA cannot be initialized at the point of definition. You have initialize it later, after defining it. So, do you really need non-constant `x` and `y`?